# Strange behavior with title field

Tags: 7, forms

I have a strange behavior (or at least this is what I think) I have two form elements. Both are required, in the first (First Name) I want to have a required field so I use `'#required' => TRUE` and `'#required' => TRUE` in the second I don't use this properties to says that the field is required, I just add this line to the title `'<span class="form-required" title="' . t('This field is required.') . '">*</span>'`. The problem is that the output of the first element is `"First name "` (with space at the end) and in the second element the output is `"Last name"` (without space at the end). See the code and the picture with the output code.

Is this a normal behavior or I missing something here?

```
  $form['general']['group-1']['prenom'] = array(
    '#prefix' => '<div class="item">',
    '#title' => t('First name'),
    '#id' => 'cf-1',
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#attributes' => array('required' => 'required'),
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );

  $form['general']['group-1']['nom'] = array(
    '#prefix' => '<div class="item">',
    '#title' => t('Last name') . '<span class="form-required" title="' . t('This field is required.') . '">*</span>',
    '#id' => 'cf-2',
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );
```

**The HTML code:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works as designed imho.

The markup of the first is generated by the form element/Drupal. By default Drupal has a space between the field title and the asterisk. That's just how it was designed.

The second time you tell the form what to add - exactly what to add. Drupal wont add a space for you, as you may not always want a space between your custom wrapper and the title. (In most cases you probably don't.)

If it is important to remove the space you can overwrite `theme_form_element()` in your theme. Check the mid to late replies (starting with kkatusic) in this thread: [How to remove asterisks from required fields?](https://www.drupal.org/node/141790)

Is there a reason why you would want to mark a field required if it isn't a required field?

Comment: This is just an example. But the really reason is because I need to make some validations with javascript so I put the asterisk for indicate that the field is required. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Well, if it is important to remove the space you can overwrite theme_form_element() in your theme. Check the mid to late replies (starting with kkatusic) in this thread: https://www.drupal.org/node/141790